# Yii CHtml::link pass url with POST request

Tags: php, yii

i have one Application in Yii and want to add one Link to but with Post request.

here is my button code

```
CHtml::link("<div class=cname1> Copy </div><br>",Yii::app()->createUrl("action/copy", array("id" => $data->id))),
```

how to make this link as Post ?

sorry i can't use button or some thing cuase its in application and i just want to make this link post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use submit in optionArray

```
$url = array('controller/action');
CHtml::link(
    'label',
    $url,
    array(
            'submit' => $url,
            'params' => array('param1' => $data['id1'], 'param2' => $data['id2']),
    )
);
```

In your case

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl("action/copy");
CHtml::link("<div class=cname1> Copy </div><br>", $url, 
        array(
            'submit' => $url,
            'params' => array("id" => $data->id))
);
```